# Iframe not stored in mysql correctly from ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, ckeditor, htmlspecialchars

I am using ckeditor to post formated text into the mysql database. When I post it converts the iframe into encoded html as if using `htmlspacialchars` but leaves the rest of the html code ok.

what I get:

```
<p>&lt;iframe frameborder=&quot;0&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; src=&quot;http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>hi lol</li>
 <li>wow</li>
 <li>yaya</li>
</ul>
```

vs what I want:

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php"></iframe></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>hi lol</li>
 <li>wow</li>
 <li>yaya</li>
</ul>
```

This causes it to appear as html code rather than rendering the iframe on the page.

I know it is not the mysql that has the problem because when I store it directly through the phpmyadmin it lets it show fine on the page, rendering the iframe.

Also it happend the same thing in tinymce so it may be a server permission thing, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor is protecting against [Cross Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks. A little searching turned up the correct way to [add an iframe with ckeditor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Rich_Text/IFrame).

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!!! also I went and did some more research on this and found that if you are using codeigniter, on line 427 in system\core\Security.php you can remove the "naughty" html tags (iframe) in this case.

Comment: @MikeDemen Your tips on **codeigniter** should be an **answer** in itself as it worked for me.